# Windows Authentication Allow Users giving 401

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have inherited an old application and I am trying to port it from an old server running 2019 to a new windows 2022 server. The application isn't working as expected on the new server, and that appears to be because of the windows authorization which is giving me a 401 error.

Within the web config file are these lines:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" /> 

<authorization>
 <allow users="domain\myusername" />
 <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

If I remove the deny users command then everyone can access the application. However for some reason with it in as it currently is I get a 401.

I've made sure that windows authenticator is enabled. I've also tried allowing all users which also works.

I'm hoping someone can see where I'm going wrong as I'm really stuck!

[image: Windows installed]

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this error messages, I suggest you use failed request tracking to view detailed error information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.